# Can OpenSSL version affect generated keys?

Tags: openssl, key, version, encryption

I need to generate pair of keys, what I have managed for a client. Even tho after exchange of keys they seem to be unable to decipher data using my key. Question I have is can different versions of OpenSSL affect key generation, what might be cause of data be unable to be deciphered?

Answer (score 0):

> ... can different versions of OpenSSL affect key generation, what might be cause of data be unable to be deciphered?

Most likely, NO.

The thing that will change is the random number generator state. The random numbers are fed to the generator, which creates the crypto parameters (like an AES key or a RSA key pair). The algorithms to create the crypto parameters (like an AES key or a RSA key pair) have been the same for years.

The only problem I am aware of is the Debian weak generator bug. That's [CVE-2008-0166](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2008-0166) or [Debian Security Advisory 1571](https://wiki.debian.org/SSLkeys). It only affected Debian due to a misunderstanding. (The Debian folks asked, but the OpenSSL folks did not provide a clear answer. So it was not clear that the Debian folks should not proceed in the particular case).

Most likely, you have a bug in your code.